# Manipulate context data to pass input to Component

Tags: reactjs

Im retrieving context data in a component as :

```
const arrayOfObjects = useContext(context);
```

If arrayOfObjects is an array of objects of type {a,b} , I want to pass input to a component like:

```
<Component options={modifiedArrayOfObjects}/>
```

Here modifiedArrayOfObjects can be an array of objects of type {a,b,c} which is modified from arrayOfObjects. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `c` doesn't have to be defined in the new type, you shouldn't have to do anything.  But if you require a value for `c` you could do this:

```
const arrayOfObjects = useContext(context);
const modified = arrayOfObjects.map(o => ({ ...o, c: 'some value' }))
// modified should now be an array of objects with a, b, and c.

// ...

<Component options={modified} />
```

Comment: Is this map function executed only once? How can I make it execute just once?

Comment: @MohitHarshan you could use `useMemo`. `const modified = useMemo(()=>arrayOfObjects.map(o => ({ ...o, c: 'some value' })),[arrayOfObjects]);`